# Как записать куки для Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

У меня на сайте должен один раз появляться popUp. После закрытия я создаю куки через js. Все отлично работает, кроме браузера safari. В нем просто не хочет создаваться куки через js. В интернете смотрел, но ничего не сработало

Comment: Предоставьте пример. По тексту гадать тяжело

Comment: Уже решил использовать localStorage.